# How to return to a different function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this example I call `fun3()` in `fun2()`, but if something special happen in `fun3()` is there a way to directly `return` to `fun1()`? without having to check this special thing in `fun2()`.

```
def fun1(num):

  res = fun2(num)

  # do something if fun3() return an error...

def fun2(num):

  res = fun3(num) # if fun3(num) return a status:error return to fun(1)

  # something else...

def fun3(num):

  if type(num) is not int:

    return {'status': 'error'}

  else: 

    # something else...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what exceptions are for

```py
def fun1(num):
  try:
    res = fun2(num)
  except Exception:
    # specific exception handling
  # will continue executing

  # something else...

def fun2(num):

  res = fun3(num) # if fun3(num) return a status:error return to fun(1)

  # something else...

def fun3(num):

  if type(num) is not int:

    raise Exception('Status Error')

  else: 

    # continue
```

You should consider using a specific Exception type, rather than just `Exception`. Fitting for this problem would be a `TypeError`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it is possible to catch an exception raised in another function.

Comment: You're not in another function, you're still in fun1(). fun3() executes in fun2() which executes in fun1(). If I put a note in an envelope, and then put the envelope in a box, the note is still in the box.  Note = fun3, envelope = fun2, and box = fun1.

Comment: I know exceptions are used to handle errors but something I need to handle warning or just info (for example `Update is not needed`), so can I create specific execption types called `fetchWarning()` and `fetchInfo()` ? just to return data in the `try` `except` in `fun1()`.

Comment: I will try to use the `Warning` module instead.

Comment: If fun3() must be called with an integer, it is an error if it is ever called with a different data type. If your function is going to do anything useful, it cannot possibly work under all possibly inputs, so we use Exceptions to handle cases where we didn't get valid input. It is good practice to throw and handle errors in your code for reasons like this. Sometimes an error in lower-level code, like fun3(), is simply caught and handled as a warning in higher-level code, like fun1(). This is very common practice, I wouldn't say you need Warning, from looking at your code I would use Exception.

Comment: The error generated with data type was for the example but I have more specific needs so I declared a `class` for custom warning type with `fetchWarning(UserWarning)` so now I can raise it and handle it into `fun1()` with `except exceptions.fetchWarning() as w :`